# Is there a way with CSS3 to specify background image translucency?

Tags: image, css, background, transparent

I found background-color:rgba(), but this only specifies a background *color's* alpha.  Is there something similar for the background *image*, when the image is specified using the CSS3 background-image()?  If there is no pure CSS3 solution, what's the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: I dont think there is an option for this.. i usually just use a PNG and make it the appropriate transparency level when saving it out.

Answer (score 2):

Simply have a container the same size *on top* with a background-color fill of your percentage rgba white.

ie.

```
html {
    background-image: url(blah.jpg);
}

body {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

Note that this technique won't work if you require the background image to be translucent on elements overlapping other elements.

Comment: Since the fourth parameter in `rgba()` defines the opacity you probably want to define `background-color: rgb(...)` the line above the style so it'll work on older browser - http://css-tricks.com/2151-rgba-browser-support/ .

Answer (score 1):

You could add a div whose sole purpose is to be the background, and give it an

```
opacity: 0.5;
```

Then have a **sibling** div that contains your content positioned on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
div.gallery   {
   background-image: url(...........);
   filter :alpha(opacity=0.8);
   opacity : .8;
}
```

Any children of this element inherit its opacity, if that is a problem do what JD Parsons said.  The filter property is for IE.  [example modified from CSS3 Visual Quickstart Guide]